# How do the player.setav absorbchance  and reflectdamage commands work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Is it 100 for 100% of the time or 1? (Is it the % or a decimal?)

Comment: same question for reflectdamage

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the example skyrim uses % where available,its just that they mark it as a number without % symbol because it makes things easier when coding.

"**player.setav speedmult**  - Where  equals your movement speed percentage as an integer value. (100 = 100%)."

Comment: Counterexample: 1 point of damageresist is worth 0.13%.